# SonarQube Scanner report upload 500 error

Tags: sonarqube

“ERROR: Error during SonarQube Scanner execution
org.sonarqube.ws.client. HttpException: Error 500”

- while running sonar scanner on my project folder I am getting above error just after completing the scan and trying to upload the report to sonarqube.the report size is approximately 450M.

Please help to fix the issue.

Here is the exact issue with screenshot:
[error screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PEFpm.png)

Comment: Is there any other errors or messages it sends back? The code 500 is an internal server error. My guess is that with a report 450M (first off why is your report 450M in size), it is too big for the server. I'd look into that first.

Comment: @Michael Added a screenshot for the error.

Comment: the interesting part would be the log from the server :D

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue on my servers as well, and it was due to the size of the report the scanner needs to send to sonarqube.

To fix this:

- or divide your scans into smaller scanner projects if possible
- or increase the memory of your server. For example for MySQL, in your my.ini/my.cnf or equivalent, inside the section `[mysqld]` make sure the parameter `max_allowed_packet` has enough to deal with the size of your report (149MB in your example). My default config was `max_allowed_packet = 16M` for a report file of 20 MB, so I changed it to `max_allowed_packet = 32M`.

After that, restart **both** your DB server and sonarqube to apply the new config.